# Handle request with Node.js & Django as backend

Tags: django, node.js, post, get, backend

I'm working on an app that uses Django/Python and Node.js as backend. For POST/GET requests Django is used. I get an error when I try to do the POST request with Node.js (using Express.js framework). Is there a way of using Node.js for POST/GET requests?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use in node.js "request" npm package.
Just example:

`npm install request`

**After:**

> `var request = require('request');`

`request.get('http://endpoint/', function (err, res) {`

```
if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(res)
    }  
});
```

Comment: I'm using express.js with body-parser. But anyway, I get a CSRF error.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get(('http://endpoint/', function (err, res) {

if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(res)
}  

})

module.exports = router;
```